# (Undergrad Real Analysis) Show that the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem implies the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

This is exercise 2.6.7(a) of Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* 2nd edition. The exercise says, "Assume the Bolzano–Weierstrass Theorem is true and use it to construct a
proof of the Monotone Convergence Theorem without making any appeal
to the Archimedean Property."

Does my proof work?

Proof: Let $(a_n)$ be monotone and bounded. By BW, there exists a convergent subsequence $(a_{n_k})$. Note that $(a_{n_k})$ is also monotone since $(a_n)$ is monotone.

Let $(a_{n_k}) \rightarrow a$. We'll attempt to show that $(a_n) \rightarrow a$ also.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$|a_{n_k} - a| < \epsilon$$ for all $k \geq N$.

Case 1: Assume $(a_n)$ is increasing. Then $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_{n_k} \leq a_{n_{k+1}}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $(a_{n_k}) \rightarrow a$, we have for all $k \geq N$ $$a - \epsilon < a_{n_k} < a + \epsilon$$ $$\Rightarrow a - \epsilon < a_{n_k} \leq a_{n_{k+1}} < a + \epsilon $$  $$\Rightarrow a - \epsilon < a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k+1}} < a + \epsilon $$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k+1}}$.

So we found a natural number, namely $n_N$, such that $a - \epsilon < a_n < a + \epsilon \Rightarrow |a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_N$. Thus, $(a_n)$ converges.

Case 2: Assume $(a_n)$ is decreasing. Then $a_n \leq a_{n-1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_{n_k} \leq a_{n_{k-1}}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $(a_{n_k}) \rightarrow a$, we have for all $k \geq N$ $$a - \epsilon < a_{n_k} < a + \epsilon$$ $$\Rightarrow a - \epsilon < a_{n_k} \leq a_{n_{k-1}} < a + \epsilon $$  $$\Rightarrow a - \epsilon < a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k-1}} < a + \epsilon $$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k-1}}$.

So we found a natural number, namely $n_N$, such that $a - \epsilon < a_n < a + \epsilon \Rightarrow |a_n - a| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_N$. Thus, $(a_n)$ converges.

Comment: There are holes in your argument:

"... for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k-1}}$. 

So we found a natural number, namely $n_N$, ..."

How did get your $n_N$ from the first statement?

Comment: Case $2$ is redundant. If $a_n$ is decreasing, then $-a_n$ is increasing and you can use the first part.

Comment: To have some good comments about your answer I would recommend that you include the exercise in your question rather than just right the number number and mention to the book

Comment: @0XLR For the increasing case, let the interval $I_N = [a_{n_N}, a_{n_{N+1}}]$ include all $a_n$ satisfying $a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k+1}}$. So we have $a_{n_N} \leq a_{n_{N+1}} \leq a_{n_{N+2}} \leq  ....$. So, each $a_n$ with $n \geq n_N$ will be in one of these intervals.

Comment: @pup2089 What is $I_N$? Is it the interval $[a_{n_N}, a_{n_{N + 1}}]$ or the set of all $a_n$ satisfying $a_{n_N} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{N + 1}}$? Those are two different things. Also, this new argument is incomplete. Why is each $a_n$ with $n \geq n_N$ necessarily in one of those intervals?

Comment: @0XLR It might be better to call $I_N$ the set of all $a_n$ satisfying $a_{n_N} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{N + 1}}$. Hmm, doesn't each $a_n$ with $n \geq n_N$ have to be in one of those sets? 
Because the infinite union $I_N \cup I_{N+1} \cup ... $ includes all of the terms of $(a_n)$ such that $n \geq n_N$.

Comment: @0XLR Maybe in my proof I should say "... for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k-1}}$ with $n \geq n_k$"?

Comment: @0XLR Sorry, I should say, for the increasing case, "... for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfying $a_{n_k} \leq a_n \leq a_{n_{k+1}}$ with $n_k \leq n \leq n_{k+1}$." Does this work?